# How can I add a specific amount of time to this datetime object I've made in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

So in PHP, I'm setting a variable which will be a date time of now, and is formatted as follows:

```
$expStartTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York') );
$formattedStartTime = $expStartTime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO');
print_r($formattedStartTime); //to be sent as a JSON value
```

the $formatted time will actually be a value in a json to be sent to a server. It is a length of an experiment. The number will be stored in a variable like `$offset = 30;` for 30 mins.

How can I programmatically write a variable as above but use the value of `$offset` to make one 30 mins in the future?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @Sammitch there's a lot of examples there; I'd like a working variable assignment please.

Comment: As over-eager as some people on SO are for points, this is not a code-on-demand service.

Comment: So you want to ADD 30 minutes to your current `$expStartTime` guess which method you have to use :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example using strtotime to just write it in plain english.  I Hope I understand your question correctly

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

    $offset =   30;
    $offsetTime = 'Now +' . $offset . ' minutes';

    $formattedStartTime = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s0', strtotime($offsetTime));
    // OR JUST date(DateTime::ISO8601, strtotime($offsetTime))

    echo $formattedStartTime;


?>
```